# ipython qtconsole - play with figure then show again

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, qtconsole

I'm using the ipython qtconsole that comes with the anaconda installation. I guess it has the %inline magic on, so everytime I do something like

```
pylab.plot(x, y)
```

It draws the plot right away, and all is good. The problem starts when I want to adjust the plot just a little, then draw it again.
Something like:

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = pylab.gca()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

But then, how do I draw 'ax' to the screen? (pylab.show() wouldn't work..)

Comment: i would edit that snippet in multiline mode so that it is all executed at the same time

Comment: or use an interactive backend (ex, QtAgg to play nice with the qtconsole).